# I have a listTile as a child of a container in flutter, I want to remove this space, and also enlarge the Image.network

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to reduce the size of the container, and also enlarge the photo

[image: Ui of the problem]
[image: source code]

Comment: would be better, if you have pasted your code instead of presenting it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `visualDensity` property to reduce the space.

The `visualDensity` value can be changed from -4.0 to 4.0.

Example:

```
ListTile(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
    title: Text("xyz")
);
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, it is that the listTile height doesn't git bigger even if you enlarge the parent widget, so Ill have to create a custom listTile